# How to pass values from a assigned variable to view?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I wanted to pass some values to the view.

The `$result` may be `0 or 1 or ''` and I tried to use this below code:

```
public function whatwedo($result='')
{
$result = array();
$result['status'] = $result;
$this->load->view('admin/whatwedo',$result);
}
public function add_whatwedo()
    {  
       //$this->load->library('form_validation');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('text-input','Title','required');
   
   if($this->form_validation->run() != true)
    {
      $result = 0;
      $this->whatwedo($result);
    }
    else
    {
     $this->load->model('admin_model');
     $result = $this->admin_model->ins_whatwedo($this->input->post());
     //print_r($result);exit();
     $this->whatwedo($result);
    }
}
```

And in the view:

```
<?php 
 print_r($status);
?>
```

But, the $status is `Array ( )`

Comment: Because you pass empty array.

Comment: Thanks @RobinSingh , But that s not the case, I edited the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
$result = array();
```

Because now the `$result` variable is an *empty array* so when you create the index `status` on result you assign it an *empty array*.

To fix you can do something like:

```
public function whatwedo($input = '')
{
    $result['status'] = $input;
    $this->load->view('admin/whatwedo', $result);
}
```

or even...

```
public function whatwedo($input = '')
{
    $this->load->view('admin/whatwedo', ["status" => $input]);
}
```